# Removing a string that does not contain letters from a list of strings in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.4

I am making a text analyzer in python. I am trying to remove any string that does not contain any letters or integers from that list. I am stuck and do not know how to do so. Currently when counting the length of my list it is including the string '-' and I do not want it to because i don't want to count this as a word. However I'd rather not use string.remove('-') because I want it to work for other inputs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want to use `re` - https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html Suggest also posting some code examples of what you have tried etc

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean is you want to filter out strings with no alphanumeric characters from a list of strings. So ['a','b','*'] => ['a','b']

Not too hard:

```
In [39]: l = ['adsfg','sdfgb','gdc','56hjfg1','&#$%^',"asfgd3$#$%^" ]
In [40]: l = filter (lambda s:any([c.isalnum() for c in s]), l)
Out[41]:  ['adsfg', 'sdfgb', 'gdc', '56hjfg1', 'asfgd3$#$%^']

In [42]:
```

Comment: Note that the question is tagged 3.4, so you'd need to toss an extra `list` in there to get that output, e.g. `list(filter(lambda s:any(c.isalnum() for c in s), l))`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the strings with alphanumeric chars in them but that *also* contain non-alphanumeric chars:

```
import re

strings = ["string", "&*()£", "$^TY?", "12345", "2wE4T", "@#~\!", "^(*4"]

strings = [s for s in strings if re.search(r'\w+', s)] #  \w matches alphanumeric chars

print strings
['string', '$^TY?', '12345', '2wE4T', '^(*4'] # now we can work with these wanted strings
```

Otherwise, to keep only the strings entirely populated by and *only by* alphanumeric chars:

`str.isalnum()` is your man:

```
strings = [s for s in strings if s.isalnum()]
print strings
['string', '12345', '2wE4T']
```

**More on re module:**

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html